# MVCC row locking vs textbook transaction behavior

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, transactions, innodb

I am confused about the theory of transactions and the implementation.
According to textbooks there are shared and exclusive locks on data items and these locks are conflicting. So if a transaction has an exclusive lock (for insert/update) then no other transaction can access the data item even for a read (select/shared lock).
This is clear so far. But this does not seem to work this way in an actual implementation.
Example in mysql:

```
session1> begin;  
session2> begin;  
session2> insert into table (id, desc) values (1234, 'test');  
session1> select * from table;
```

The select of session 1 is executed. It is only blocked *only* if I replace it with `select ...for update`
But I don't undestand why the plain select does not block. It should get a shared lock which would conflict with an exclusive/write lock.
It seems that this is due to MVCC but does this mean that MVCC does not adhere to textbook descriptions about transaction interactions?
The same behavior I see for a `DELETE` instead of an `INSERT`

Comment: I updated with `select *` without where since it show the same behavior and accesses all rows to avoid sidetracks

Answer (score 1):

MVCC is somewhat different to traditional locks in that, casually speaking:

1. *writers don't block readers*
2. readers don't block anyone, and don't get blocked by anyone.

This is a critical feature if you want scalability, as it avoids a lot of contention. It has a problem tough: in several cases MVCC does not behave as you could intuitively expect. Nevertheless, MVCC is too useful to ignore, so you just learn of its nuances. The most typical one is that you can use `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level and get a final state that you could not get with any serial execution of the involved transactions.

In your particular case the `SELECT` does not block because of 1. However, the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` does block because it acts as "sort of" a writer, and so it gets blocked by another writers.

Recommended links:

- [About MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)
- [About ANSI/ISO `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Serializable)
- [About serializable transactions and their interaction with MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_isolation#Serializable_Snapshot_Isolation)
- [About *serializability*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializability)